# Contact mechanics in Drake

Tags: drake

I have a general question regarding the accuracy of the contact mechanics of Drake. So far I have tried some different open source robotic simulation tools. They all appear to have the same problem when simulating the contact between two meshed objects, that the objects are unstable and fall off each other. Eg. in Gazebo I tried stacking two meshed objects (see https://youtu.be/_4qQh3pvAZ8) without success.

I am trying to learn assembly tasks using reinforcement learning. RL needs a lot of iterations (simulations) before it converges to a valid policy. Since RL needs to learn something in a reasonable time it is not possible to increase the accuracy (by reducing the step size), because that will also increase the computation time too much. In the end the only solution was to go to Adams, which is an (expensive) multibody mechanics software toolbox, where there is more freedom to optimize the contact between two specific objects. I also tried the simulator Klampt, where the contact is more accurate but it also adds a layer around each object.

Today I came across Drake and saw that in the videos the contact mechanics are really accurate. But most of the obects seem non-meshed objects (blocks and cilinders), of which the behavior is easier to approximate. So I am wondering if Drake also exhibits inaccurate behavior, like the video, with meshed objects stacked on top of each other? Also if the speed of the simulation is around the same speed as the real world?

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment specifically on what may be causing your instability in other applications (e.g., Gazebo), but I can shed some light into contact stability in Drake.

Drake's default contact model is a very frequently imlemented "point contact" model (discussed [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__drake__contacts.html)). Given two bodies in contact, intersection between the representative collision geometries is detected and the *amount* of penetration is reported by a pair of points representing the maximum amount of penetration (and the force is applied at that contact point).

For a sphere on a plane, this is perfectly sufficient, because the contact between a rigid sphere and plane *is* a single point. For stacking boxes, it is a poor approximation; the contact interface between two stacked boxes isn't a point, but a polygon where force would be applied across the full contact interface. Representing it as a point introduces artificial torques.

Drake has an additional contact model -- one that is currently in development and incomplete. It is called "hydroelastic" contact and instead of representing contact by measurement at a single point, it computes an entire surface of contact, distributing the contact force over that full surface. As you might imagine, this leads to far more stable contact. However, because the model is not complete, there are restrictions on how you can use it and when it'll actually provide value. However, the feature is available in Drake's public API and you are free to investigate it. A basic explanation of the characterization can be found [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_contact_surface.html).

Some further thoughts based on the details above:

1. General, non-convex meshes.

   - For the point contact model, non-convex meshes are not directly supported. Instead, it uses the *implicit* convex hull of that mesh (which can negatively impact performance). If you know the mesh to be convex, you can declare it as such and Drake can use techniques which may improve the efficiency.
   - The hydroelastic contact model *does* support non-convex meshes, but they must be for strictly "rigid" objects. And that model only computes contact between soft and rigid objects. So, if you're hoping to compute contact between two non-convex meshes, you won't be able to use this model. In its current state, you need to model things as contact between rigid meshes and soft primitives. (e.g., you can create a "soft" box to serve as a table, and place any number of rigid, non-convex meshes on it stably, but contact between those rigid objects will *not* be stable).
2. Tricks for stable contact

   - One "trick" for getting better stability in contact with a point contact model is to change the representation of the collision geometry. Place small spheres on the surface of the object. The goal is to ensure that when it is in contact with other objects, you will get contact at *multiple* points. The challenge here is placing the spheres such that meaningful contact will generally get you at least three results.

Comment: There is a paper describing hydroelastic contact: Elandt et al. 2019 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8968548 (it's called "pressure field contact" there). Available in arXiv if you don't have access.

Comment: [This is the arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.11433.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Would these two examples in Drake, answer your questions about non-convex meshes, please?

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/hydroelastic/ball_plate

[image]

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/hydroelastic/python_nonconvex_mesh

[image]
[image]